# How can I set maximum concurrent users during my Selenium load test? Load test opens more concurrent users in parallel than I set

Tags: selenium, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jsr223

While running my load test for 1 or 5 or 10 or so concurrent users, the test runs far more users in parallel. it starts new users before the first thread finishes even though Start thread count is set to some number. 
Can I avoid it by setting proper delays? If so how should the delay be set? 
I also tried solving it by calling `driver.quit()` at the end of the test in a `try catch` block so threads close after exdcution but looks like it doesn't closes the threads (Chrome browser windows in this case) with errors in it.

```
try{
WebElement myDynamicElement3 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[text()='hello']")));
}catch(Exception e) {
    throw new AssertionError("Element not found....", e);
}
driver.quit();
```

Please help which approach should I try and how.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to provide the answer without seeing your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration, the way you instantiate the [WebDriver](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html), the way you're handling WebDriver instances between Thread Group iterations, etc.

In the meantime I can only recommend considering using [WebDriver Sampler Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) or at least look into its [source code](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver) - this way you should learn how to properly instantiate and shut down the browser instances.

And last but not the least, using real browsers for load testing is not the best idea as modern browsers are **very** resource intensive, each browser instance requires full CPU core and at least 1 GB of RAM and you can simulate at least 100 virtual users using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers at cost of one browser instance.